# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::index(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\

Tags: laravel-8

I have error:

> ArgumentCountError Too few arguments to function
> App\Http\Controllers\ProjectController::index(), 0 passed in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ContentBaseApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php
> on line 54 and exactly 1 expected

[image]

In my `ProjectController.php` How can i solve this
This is my `ProjectController.php`

```
public function index($product_id)
{
    // $projects = Project::whereIn('product_id',Product::where('user_id',Auth::id())->pluck('id')->toArray())->latest()->paginate(20);

    $product = Product::where('user_id', Auth::id())->where('id', $product_id)->firstOrFail();
    $projects = Project::where('product_id', $product->id)->latest()->paginate(20);

    return view('projects.index', compact('projects'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

[image]

I wrote index method code because I want; suppose I have two id `1` & `2` if I click id `1` it will take me to `index.blade.php` where I can upload new data like `data_1` and `data_2` those data will show on index.blade.php

And if I click id `2` it will take me to `index.blade.php` where I don't want to see data of id `1` as I uploaded data1 and data2.

If I upload new data for id `2` I can see those data in `index.blde.php`

Answer (score 2):

The `index` function on your `ProjectController` expects one argument (`$product_id`) as per the error message you're seeing.

Whenever you access of reference the `index` route, it needs to be provided with the `$product_id` parameter otherwise an error will be thrown (the one you're seeing).

If you're following convention, what you likely want to do is define two routes:

1. An `index` route that displays all `resources` and takes zero arguments
2. A `show` route that displays information for a single `resource` and requires one argument which identifies a `resource`.

For example:

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/projects', [ProjectController::class, 'index')
    ->name('projects.index');

Route::get('/projects/{product}', [ProjectController::class, 'show'])
    ->name('projects.show');
```

**ProjectController.php**

```php
public function index()
{
    return view('projects.index', [
        'projects' => Project::paginate(20),
    ]);
}

public function show(Product $product)
{
    return view('projects.show', [
        'projects' => $product->projects()->latest()->paginate(20),
    ]);
}
```

If you visit `/projects` you will return all `project` resources, but if you visit `/projects/2` you will get only the `projects` related to `Product` with `id` of `2`.

You can use the [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) helper to generate your `URLs`.

```html
<a href="{{ route('projects.show', 2) }}"> ... </a>
```

That would create a link that would take you to the `projects` for `product` `2`.

Comment: Brother I want index method will return only projects of special product. I don`t want to user my present index. Can you help me with that i am stuck on this for 1 days

Comment: @AbdullahAlShahed I've already explained how you can do that in my answer.